# NestedScrollView throw error "android.view.InflateException" when use nestedScrollEnabaled attribute

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-coordinatorlayout, android-nestedscrollview

I have *ViewPager* inside *NestedScrollView* and in order to make my *ViewPager* attach the right height and scroll attributes I added `android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true"` to my *NestedScroll..*, here is a snap for my design :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent">

        <items .... />
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/nestedScroll"
        android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/viewPager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_7sdp"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/_7sdp"/>
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

The issue: Is when I set `android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true"` to true I got those exception:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{somePackege}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class <unknown>
```

AND

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v4.view.NestedScrollingChildHelper.setNestedScrollingEnabled(boolean)' on a null object reference
```

I'm confused if `android:nestedScrollingEnabled="@otherAtt"` take another attribute (Not `boolean`).

And I'm was wondering if there a better approach to reach this behavior.

Answer (score 6):

Ok so the way I made your layout work is to not use the `setNestedScrollingEnabled` method in the xml and instead set it in runtime inside your activity or fragment like so:

```
NestedScrollView view = (NestedScrollView) findViewById(R.id.nestedScroll);
view.setNestedScrollingEnabled(true);
```

Doing it this way also reduces the API level needed, as to `setNestedScrollingEnabled` in xml requires API level 21 or higher.

Comment: ``=setNestedScrollingEnabled in xml requires API level 21 or higher` true>

and setting `setNestedScrollingEnabled(true);` using java didn't crash application, but it's doesn't the most important thing.. it's dosen't set the right hegiht for viewPager, the viewPager compressed and didn't attached to the view.

Comment: 3 things made this layout crash for me, the two times you used  `app:layout_behavior` and the time you used `android:nestedScrollingEnabled`, so i removed the `layout_behavior` and move the `nestedScrollingEnabled`

Comment: Why do you use NestedScrollView, is there a specific reason? Because ViewPager is able to handle scrolling to transition to and from its fragments.

Comment: Did you see the `CoordinatorLayout` ? I used it to use `app:layout_behavior` and that's a scrolling behavior, also viewPager contain recycleView that's another scroll. so it's required to use nestedscrollview.

Comment: Ok, so how about if we remove the `NestedScrollView` in this layout and instead, call `setNestedScrollingEnabled` for each of the `RecycleView's`?

Comment: It's not solution for my case but I tried it with no success.

Comment: Ah fair enough, sorry I couldn't be any more help!

Comment: No prob, Thanks for your help :)